# CSS3 animate doesn't play again on removeClass followed by addClass, but alters on toggleClass

Tags: jquery, html, css

If I do:

```
jQuery('#test').removeClass("change");
console.log(jQuery('#test').attr("class"));
jQuery('#test').addClass("change");
```

CSS3 `animate` bind to this class shows only first time.

```
.change {
  ...
  animation: redToTransparent 1s;
  animation-play-state: running;
  -webkit-animation: redToTransparent 1s;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
}
```

**Code in action**:
http://jsfiddle.net/adamovic/ato5akjx/

If you click on the button a few times, the animation doesn't repeat. 
**Why?**

But it plays every second time, when using `.toggleClass()`.

Browsers tested: Chrome, Firefox

Comment: Do you think that `.toggleClass()` is the same as calling `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` together?

Answer (score 7):

It looks like there has to be a delay between adding/remove classes.

Adding a delay of 100ms seems to work in Chrome/FF/IE.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/5jc9ww8u/)

```
$('#mybutton').on('click', function () {
    $('#test').removeClass("change");
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#test').addClass("change");
    }, 100);
});
```

---

If you're using jQueryUI, you could also use the following:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/e4y6kk50/)

```
$('#mybutton').on('click', function () {
    $('#test').removeClass("change").addClass("change", 100);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, looks like a timing issue. css-tricks has the solution: reload the element on the page. http://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/

Since I hate to work with timers and delays, it would look something like this:

```
jQuery('#mybutton').click(function() {

   newone = jQuery('#test').clone(true);
   jQuery('#test').remove();
   jQuery('.container').append(newone);

   newone.addClass('change');

 });
```

Comment: The css-tricks post you linked seems to have a new solution by measuring `offsetWidth` to force a reflow. I don't what the difference between this and your solution are performance-wise, but the reflow version seems easier.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is this. when the page loads,

```
$('h1, h2, h3, li').each(function() {
    if (isScrolledIntoView(this) === true) {
      $(this).addClass('animate__animated');
      $(this).addClass('animate__bounceIn');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('animate__animated');
      $(this).removeClass('animate__bounceIn');
    }
  });
```

then, i also have this script, which runs every time you scroll the bar:

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
    $('h1, h2, h3, li').each(function() {
      if (isScrolledIntoView(this) === true) {
        $(this).addClass('animate__animated');
        $(this).addClass('animate__bounceIn');
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('animate__animated');
        $(this).removeClass('animate__bounceIn');
      }
    });
 });
```

HOWEVER, DO NOT apply the 'animation-name' attribute in your style sheet. If you do this, the jQuery Scroll function will still remove and add the classes as intended, however the animations will not run because the element will ALWAYS have 'animate_animated' aplied. So, what i'm saying, is LET THE JAVASCRIPT apply the animation classes to whatever you want when the page loads (the first JS snippet). DO NOT apply the animation classes in your css. So for instance, you can put:

```
animation-duration: 6.5s;
animation-delay: 10.0s;
```

in your style sheet. But DO NOT put:

```
 animation-name: bounceIn;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
```

in your stylesheet.